# Can DPAK be used in a through hole PCB if desperate?

Tags: soldering

I purchased the wrong component, and have no time to order another one. What is the best way to go about doing this on a PCB with the plated holes?

[IRFR9214PBF](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/vishay/irfr9214pbf/?qs=iXwvDCb7I7hjm2Ycf0pGIQ%3D%3D&countrycode=US&currencycode=USD)

I have a very small heat sink that is slightly larger than the size of the chip. It came with my Raspberry Pi as a heat sink for the baby sized chip on it.

The backside of the chip is the drain, left pin front-side is gate, right pin source.

[image]

Schematic:

[image]

The circuit is a pulse generation controller that drives an ultrasonic transducer with 100ns pulses, at a sending rate of about 200-800Hz.

The energy in each pulse is very low.

Cadence simulates the circuit as I'd expect. I can post waves graphs if requested.

The BJTs do a good job of controlling the current flow for the desired amount of time.  Don't get spooked because of the high voltage going through the transformer.   The Zener diode avalanches at 220V, and the power MOSFET is rated for 250V.

Comment: How much power does the transistor have to dissipate?

Comment: What is  your required power dissipation?

Comment: " Power dissipation levels up to 1.5 W
are possible in typical surface mount applications."

Comment: You can certainly solder it onto that PCB, but the power dissipation capability will be reduced. Normally a DPAK relies on thermal transfer to the large copper pad. But that is a big package, and if you put the heatsink on the front of it, it can probably dissipate a Watt indefinitely without self-destructing.

Comment: You are quoting from the transistor datasheet. But that is not what Spehro and I are asking. We want to know how much it WILL dissipate based on the circuit you are building. What does the circuit do? Do you have a schematic?

Comment: Would the best way to solder it be vertically, with the gate/source pins going through holes, and have a wire soldered inbetween the heatsink and the drain?

Comment: I would solder it down surface-mount style with the drain on those oval pads, and solder the gate and source to through-hole pads. I would put the heatsink on the front side of the plastic case. But whether this will work all depends on how much power it has to dissipate, so please answer the questions!

Comment: I'll be honest, I ain't got a damn idea how much power it is gonna dissipate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86356/discussion-between-mkeith-and-snowg).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When doing hand assembly you have a lot of options that aren't practical in production.

you could surface-mount it on that matrix board - if it gets too hot solder thick copper wires into the holes under the the drain pad to act as a heatsink. solder conducts heat better than any affordable non-metallic interface material.
or you could plan ahead and lay down some copper sheet under the drain pad when mounting it and extend the other tabs to reach the circuit board.

A DPAK is basically the same as a TO220 with the leads bent and bits cut off, you could solder pins onto it (that middle tab connects to the drain pad just like in a TO220) and use it through-hole, and optionally solder or clamp a heatsink to the drain pad.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest thing to do is to grab some copper clad pcb and make a quick smd to dip adapter board. You don't need to etch it, for an IC as big as a dpak you can just cut groves on the pcb using a dremel cutting wheel or drill bit. And use wire or a standard 0.1" header to connect it to the pcb you have there.

This, but bigger
[image]
<sub>(source: [instructables.com](https://cdn.instructables.com/FE9/YHD8/GI0TDU8Z/FE9YHD8GI0TDU8Z.LARGE.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 5):

You can surface mount your DPAK on the perfboard easily. I use SMDs on perfboard all the time: 0805/1206 passives and SOT23's fit nicely between the pads.

Problem is dissipation, so you could use a small bit of copper sheet, like 1cm wide 3cm long. 0.5mm thickness works well. You can bend it in a L shape and solder the transistor on the bottom part of the "L", and then surface mount that on your perfboard, while the top part sticks out and acts as a heat sink.

Another solution: these aren't DPAK but you get the idea.

[image]

You can use a piece of blank copperclad PCB and solder the device on it, right on the edge, with the legs sticking out. Add a wire for the missing center leg and solder it to the same bit of PCB. It will also act as a heat sink. In the picture above I used copper shims from aliexpress, which dramatically improves thermal resistance between these tiny transistors and the heat sink. But if it's only for a few watts, a piece of blank pcb is fine.

Comment: Can you clarify how the copper shim improves between the transistors and heatsink? Did you mean between the transistors and ambient air? Or is there another heatsink not pictured?

Comment: Yeah, heatsink is not pictured. When you press these transistors on a heatsink with a clip, since they're tiny, the limiting factor for Rth is the small surface area of thermal interface material (silpad). The copper shim has a much larger contact area with the heat sink, which means a larger area of silpad, and lower thermal resistance.